# Does Skype leave enough information behind to allow an attacker to discover the users' password?

Tags: security, skype

While travelling, I've noticed some internet shops that offer a skype calling service, which makes me wonder. All other threats aside (ie, ignoring keyloggers and screen scrapers, etc...):

Assuming that the user logs out once he's done with the service, is it possible to find out information about the call (or other info, such as users' password) from the files Skype stores to disk as part of its regular operation?

Answer (score 2):

If you share your password with someone else's machine, you're potentially sharing your password with the owner of that machine.

Aside from the fact that there will be forensic traces from the pagefile, the memory, the caches, potential malware capturing your password, hardware keyloggers, and so on; in an Internet cafe they can probably just watch you type it in via the CCTV in the corner of the room or just dust the keyboard for prints.

The simple answer is if you're worried about your password, don't use it in an Internet Cafe. Malware can and does get installed on those machines (sometimes deliberately by the management) so beware of ever divulging your credentials in such a circumstance.